# Flutter - SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 46208

Tags: android, postgresql, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL with Flutter. I installed PostgreSQL on the computer.
I wrote a code:

```
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        var connection = PostgreSQLConnection(
            "localhost", 5432, "instagram",
            username: "postgres", password: "postgres");
        try {
          await connection.open();
          await connection.execute("show databases");
  //        await connection.execute("INSERT INTO users (Username, 'Name, Surname, Photo) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test')");
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      },
      child: null,
    )
```

But it gives error `SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno=111), address=localhost, port=46208`. From where? How can I solve it? I've been doing research on many sources for hours, but I still haven't been able to solve it.

---

[image]

Comment: What's your target machine? Linux. Android, Windows?

Comment: `port=46208` seems to indicate a proxy somewhere, as it doesn't say `5432`.

Comment: @RichardHeap Hello. What do you mean by target machine? I am trying to run the application on windows 10

Comment: Try a pure Dart project first to confirm connectivity. Also try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. Update the question with the output of `netstat -an | findstr 5432`

Comment: @RichardHeap I tried replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` but nothing changed.
. I updated question.

Comment: `? I am trying to run the application on windows 10` Then what does this have to do with Android,? Your setup is completely unclear. Which application?

Comment: @blackapps My English is bad ve I not understand your say.

Comment: Good point by blackapps... Why do you have the question tagged with the "Android" tag?

Comment: Because I try connect on Android Emulator.

Comment: I misunderstood because my English is bad. I am sorry